# how to detect the algorithm of a hashed string

Tags: c#, hash

I have a software which stores passwords using an unknown hashing method. for example if the 123456789 set as the password, it would be stored in the database by two fields which are 'salt' (seems that the salt is generated randomly) and 'hashed'. And I need to know how the software reaches to that hashed string.

as an example for the origial string: 123456789

the salt is: ifWIg1IB

hashed is: QkKtpxSqd+kIH2EuMkNdWV44B2g=

I need to know it because of making an integrated login system via this hashed password. I think it is very important to avoid make lots of username and password for each person in an office.

with the best respects

Comment: Isn't the whole point of password security to prevent you from reverse-engineering it?

Comment: You take the bytes of the original string, then you combine them with the bytes of the salt in some way (depends on the algorithm). Then you apply a hashing function one or multiple times on the result.

Comment: @buffjape: I don't think the OP wants to know the original password (since that is for popular hashing algorithms (close to) impossible), but wants to know the algorithm. But indeed, although obfuscation is not enough secure, it is one of the additional measures one can take.

Comment: Why do you want to know? Even if you knew the hash method, unless it's a very old and broken one you'll never backwards engineer the password. Don't waste your time.

Comment: Other than the length of the hashed result providing a clue, you are stuck with applying all of the available algorithms to the password/salt and seeing which matches. It is common for systems to store the salt, algorithm identification and hash so that old algorithms can be supported, but retired. For example, if Elbonian42 is found to be weak then you would store all _new_ password hashes using a more secure algorithm. Elbonian42 would still be supported to allow old accounts access, perhaps with a suggestion or requirement that they update their password at the next login.

Comment: this software is working in my office and I want to merge and make all of the  username and passwords united, means that I need to use the usr and pass of this software for logging in other systems.

Comment: If you're trying to backwards engineer the hash into the original data then give up now, you're wasting your time.

Comment: Are your example values valid? If so the process is `base64(sha1(concat(salt, password)))`.

Comment: Please update your question with exactly what you have access to in the original software as well as what you need to do.

Comment: @Mad Myche Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'hashed' output is a base-64 encoded string. Decoding the string results in a 20-byte digest. SHA-1 produces 20-byte hashes so it looks like the generation process is:

```
base64(sha1(combine(salt, password)))
```

there are two obvious approaches to combining the salt and password plaintext - append or prepend the salt to the password. If you prepend the salt you end up with the following algorithm to generate the encoded digest:

```
public static string GenPasswordString(string password, string salt)
{
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt + password);
    using (var alg = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed())
    {
        byte[] hashBytes = alg.ComputeHash(bytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
    }
}
```

and

```
GenPasswordString("123456789", "ifWIg1IB") == "QkKtpxSqd+kIH2EuMkNdWV44B2g="
```